# Does not existence of partial derivatives at a point tells us that the function is not differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

This question arose after my calculus test in which the told us: Show that $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{2x^3}{x^2 +y^2}&\text{ if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0&\text{ if }(x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. I showed that the partials do not exist in $(0,0)$ thus the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If in doubt, the first thing to do should have been to look at the definition of differentiability that was given in your course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof that $f$ isn't differentiable.**

If $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, we would have
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y) - f(0,0) -2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0,$$

as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$.

But
$$\frac{f(x,y) - f(0,0) -2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{-2xy^2}{\left(x^2+y^2 \right)^{3/2}} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

for $x=y$. Hence $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Because if the function $f$ is differentiable at a point $p$ of its domain, then the directional derivatives exist for every direction $v$. And the partial derivatives are a particular case of directional derivatives.

The only problem is that in your specific example, the partial derivatives *do* exist. In fact $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$.

Comment: how did you find that?

Comment: @T.Katsipis $f(x,0)=2x\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=2$ and $f(0,y)=0\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$.

Comment: I see , thank you.

Comment: @T.Katsipis If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In fact you haven't answer to the question which is "prove that $f$ isn't differentiable".

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: He answered the only question in sight, which is the one given in the title of the question...

Comment: @HansLundmark It is true that the title and the "Show that..." in the question are quite confusing.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It turns out that $f$ **is** differentiable at $(0,0)$ (and that $Df_{(0,0)}(x,y)=2x$).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos José, in fact $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. See answer below.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Right. My mistake.